# Sudoers, allow user to use root alias

Tags: linux, sudo, bashrc

Actually, my root have to aliases:

```
alias unpool='/path/to/my/scripts/unpool.sh'
alias pool='/path/to/my/scripts/pool.sh'
```

I have the same for my user in `~/.bashrc`

I defined my `/etc/sudoers.d/user` with

```
user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/cp
user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/scripts/pool.sh
user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/scripts/unpool.sh
```

But logged with my user, I can't do `sudo unpool`, it ask me my password

What can I do ?

Comment: Your shell would need to first expand that alias and pass the fully qualified command path to `sudo`. Simpler might be `alias unpool='sudo /path/to...'`

Comment: I believe it should say `ALL=(ALL)` not `ALL=(root)`.